# Flask Sql-Alchemy, sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: PAM authentication failed for user 'abc'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a flask application, whick uses flask-sqlalchemy library to communicate with postgres server in AWS RDS.

The application works fine with just username and password. But i created a IAM user and allow him to login to postgres using the token (uses boto3's function 'generate_db_auth_token()'). using token login the get the following error.

'sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  PAM authentication failed for user "abc"'

This is the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI i am using with token,

```
"postgresql+psycopg2://"+get_conn()[0]['user']+":"+str(get_conn()[0]['password'])+"@"+get_conn()[0]['host']+":"+str(get_conn()[0]['port'])+"/common?sslmode=verify-ca&sslrootcert=/home/ec2-user/root.pem"
```

Am i doing anything wrong here.

Comment: The problem here does not seem to be SQLAlchemy. Can you extract the database_uri and try to connect to it directly using an app like Postico, PGAdmin, or DataGrip/PyCharm?

Comment: the RDS is running in private subnet, i dont think right now i can connect using those applications.   Interesting thing is using **psycopg2.connect()** i am able to connect even using IAM token, but not able to get same behavior using sqlalchemy.  Do you think the characters in token used for password might be the issue?

Comment: That is very well possible, especially `:@/`, etc. Try removing those or limiting special characters to `.,-_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with URL construction, use this to construct URL if you are using AWS token for authentication.

```
sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL('postgresql+psycopg2', username='postgres', password='password', host='localhost', port=5432, database='common')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```py
sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
    drivername='postgresql+psycopg2',
    username='postgres',
    password='password',
    host='localhost',
    port=5432,
    database='common'
)
```